# Create View giving SQL7029

Tags: errors, iseries, db2-midrange

If relevant, I'm using IBM i V7R1M0.

I have some code in C#:

```
var generateSqlSql = $@"
CALL QSYS2.GENERATE_SQL(
    '{obj.Name}',
    '{obj.Library}',
    'VIEW',
    CREATE_OR_REPLACE_OPTION => '1',
    HEADER_OPTION => '0',
    COMMENT_OPTION => '1',
    PRIVILEGES_OPTION => '0',
    LABEL_OPTION => '0'
)";
...
//get results
//split on semicolon
//change library
//write back to database
```

The sql that it's then trying to write is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AMMLIBC.BBI_USER_MY_VIEW FOR SYSTEM NAME         BBIU_00001 ( 
/* view columns */ ) 
AS 
/*view definition */
RCDFMT BBIU_00001
```

When I try to run it, it gives the following error:

```
iDB2SQLErrorException: SQL7029 New name BBIU_00001 is not valid.
```

...Why? What's causing this, and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

The view already existed in both the original library and the target library, but with different system names.

Adding this line fixed the problem:

```
SYSTEM_NAME_OPTION => '0',
```